# If $A^2-A+I=0$ then $A^{-1}$ is..

Tags: matrices, algebra-precalculus

If $A^2-A+I=0$ then $A^{-1}$ is..

$1$. $A^{-2}$.

$2$. $A+I$.

$3$. $I-A$.

$4$. $A$.

My Attempt:

$$A^2-A+I=0$$
$$A^2=A-I$$

what should I do further?

Comment: What do you mean by plus or minus the square root of a matrix? That is not generally something you can compute.

Comment: It's not that it would be difficult to find one, it's more like there could easily exist really really many of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another hint: $$A-A^2 = I\\\text{multiply with } A^{-1} \text{ both sides}\\I-A = A^{-1}$$

Oh wait, that wasn't a hint.

Comment: There is a small caveat that when you multiply $A^{-1}$, you did not yet show $A$ is invertible. While $A(I-A)=I$ just show that $A$ is invariable. But it's not a big deal, because the option of the multiple choice assumes that $A^{-1}$ exists.

Comment: @YujieZha: Yes we can switch to say that in the case that $A^{-1}$ exists, then the multiplication is valid and it must be $I-A$. Then from there try and see if it fits.

Comment: Cool, that mental process is sufficient, good post (+1)

Comment: @YujieZha good to have someone check, I'm taxing my brain with romanian right now so it would not be surprising if there is some slip somewhere. ;)

Comment: No worries, glad to help :)

Answer (score 9):

Hint: $I = A(I - A)$.Can you see it?

Comment: No. please further elaborate..

Comment: $A^{-1}$ is the matrix which, when you multiply it by $A$, gives the identity matrix $I$. There is only one such matrix, and the equation $I=A(I-A)$ (which is obtained by rearranging the given equation) shows that $I-A$ is one such matrix. Therefore...